# Error to use date as argument and defaults in positional argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am trying argparse where I wanted to get as date type with format 'YYYYMMDD'. If not provided wanted to use current date.

Here is my code but I get:

```
usage:  [optional arguments]
: error: too few arguments
```

I tried both positional and optional arguments.

```
from datetime import date
class ValidateArgs(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if values is None:
            print("value is None")
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, date.today())
        else:
            print("value fine")
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

import argparse
import datetime
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='xxx', usage='%(prog)s [optional arguments]')
parser.add_argument('offset', help='Number of days')
parser.add_argument('fromDte', action=ValidateArgs)
```

1. How to tell the argparser that I am looking for date type 'datetime.date(2018, 9, 5)'
2. How to resolve using default?
   I invoke as parser.parse_args('2'.split())
   I am using python 2.7